# How to find an upper bound for a norm with power less than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

I need to find an upper bound for $$\|x-y\|_2^\nu$$ in which $\nu \in [0,1]$. I was wondering if $\|x-y\|_2^2$ can be considered as an upper bound. or $\|x\|+\|y\|$?

Comment: In the one-dimensional case with $\Vert\cdot\Vert =\vert\cdot\vert$ it's already the case that $\vert x-y \vert^\nu \leq \vert x-y\vert^2$ and $\vert x-y \vert^\nu \leq \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert$ can both be false.  Do you have a reason to expect one of these expressions to be an upper bound?  You'll get a better answer if you tell us the context of your question.

Comment: If $0<\|x-y\|\le 1$ the upper bound is $1.$  If $ |x-y\|\ge 1$ the upper bound is $\|x-y\|.$

Comment: I would like to prove a theorem and I need an upper bound for $\|x-y\|^\nu$.